# Extract wikipedia pages revisions - to compare sentences correction

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I need to extract all wikipedia pages revisions (to compare sentences correction) to hold the changes between the most recent version and the previous version. I'm new to this domain, any one have an idea? using java/c#/python
thanks

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried working with mediaWiki API

Comment: then show your code